# How should I make the navbar to be on the same line with the logo and header

Tags: css, menu, navigation, css-float, navbar

[I want to put them on the same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tAsx.jpg)

[I've tried float it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtY9V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what is the problem unless you show me the html file. Perhaps try to add the following line of code in the **.site-heading**

```
  display: flex;
```

If tha doesn't work please provide the html where both logo and navbar are located.

Comment: Your first sentence is the reason for voting to close the question, not answer it. Do not answer such questions that do not provide markup or code. Anything you provide will only be a wild guess.  [answer]

Comment: Thank your for your feedback. You are right, I should have provided more info in my answer and collect more info about the problem before I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use > `display: flex;`

For example, here is the HTML structure of a `header(.header-block)` which contains
a) logo
b) main navigation
c) client login CTA

```
<header class="header-block">
    <div class="site-logo">
        
    </div><!-- / site logo -->

    <div class="navbar">
        
    </div><!-- / main nav area -->

    <div class="client-login">
        
    </div><!-- / client login -->
</header>
```

In the CSS you can add following codes -

```
.header-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    direction: ltr;         /* --- optional --- */
    align-items: center;    /* --- for positioning the child elements vertically center --- */
}
```

I hope you will get the desired result.

Here you can find the example ->
http://wtaxtest.designshowcase.co.za